# Can I change which outlet on a circuit has the GFCI reset switch?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Due to how I want to lay out furniture in a room, the location of the outlet that contains the GFCI reset button is not convenient. Can I simply swap that outlet for another on the circuit and have the GFCI reset switch outlet be in a more convenient place? If so, are there any concerns I need to keep in mind other than making sure the breaker is turned off?

This is in the basement, the GFCI came with the house. Does it need the GFCI because it is in the basement?

If no, are there alternatives that still keep us protected but keep us from having the reset on this specific outlet?

Comment: What room is it? and why do you need a gfci outlet?  If so and you want the downstream outlets protected, no  you can't just move it.

Comment: Another option is to replace the breaker with a GFCI one.  Will not need GFCI outlets and will not need to worry about furniture being in the way of the reset.

Comment: But wait:  Why does reseting a GFCI outlet in an indoor space need to be convenient?  Maybe a more important question would be how to eliminate causes of frequent ground faults!

Comment: @jay613 it's not a huge mystery or diabolical con here. The panel and GFCI reset outlet are both in the basement a mere 20 feet from each other. The GFCI reset outlet is in a corner of a basement room where I would like to put a corner table with a bench. We do not have frequent ground faults, but I want to be planful and be able to reset the circuit without having to move a large corner bench.

Comment: @Forklift Murphy's Law of Electricity says that you're much more likely to develop ground faults as soon as you put that heavy piece of furniture in front of the GFCI outlet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option you have is to move the GFCI to the next outlet "downstream", then eliminate the original outlet.  This will result in the GFCI button being in a (hopefully) more convenient place, plus all outlets will remain GFCI-protected.

Normally, this isn't something people want to do at all since it means they lose an outlet.  In your case, however, you'll be blocking the outlet with a piece of furniture.  If the piece of furniture makes the outlet inaccessible and unusable, you likely won't even notice that the outlet is gone.  Should you decide in the future to redecorate and are no longer blocking the outlet, you always have the option of moving the GFCI back and regaining your outlet.

Comment: Hey! This is a good idea!

Answer (score 16):

An easy alternative is a GFCI breaker for that circuit. It will give the same or better protection, and will not need to worry about climbing over/under furniture to reset.

Change the outlet to a plain one if you use a GFCI breaker.

Comment: This answer assumes running to the basement is more convenient than moving the sofa out of the way.  I'm not buying it, I want proof!  :)

Comment: @jay613   OP states it is in/for the basement.  A sofa might be heavy(old good, new not that much), walking/running is good for you.   Should do more of it myself.  Of course if the panel is outside and a blizzard, you have a point.

Comment: @crip659 If you have an electrical panel that's outside, and have to access it during a blizzard, I'm pretty sure you have other problems to worry about.

Comment: @jay613 If you have to reset your GFCI so often that convenience matters, you have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 11):

Not always - you have to be careful. GFCIs will only protect outlets downstream from it. So you will need to make sure that:

1. You know which outlets are on the GFCI circuit.
2. You only move the GFCI upstream (closer to the breaker).

More than likely the GFCI is already first in flow in the room. So it's probably unlikely you can move it without unprotecting circuits.

Answer (score 8):

GFCIs are required in basements. You can switch to a model where every outlet has its own GFCI, or at least the first few.

1. Trip the GFCI.
2. Search exhaustively for every outlet that is now dead because you tripped the GFCI.
3. Buy a GFCI receptacle for each of those outlets.
4. **Read the instructions for how to attach 2 wires to the "LINE" terminals.**
5. **Do not remove the warning tape** covering the LOAD terminals.
6. Do not use the LOAD terminals at all.
7. On the first original GFCI receptacle, move all wires to the LINE terminals.
8. Install other GFCIs with all wires on LINE.

Now you will have GFCI outlets at each outlet.

All your plain outlets are legally required to have "GFCI Protected" markings. Most people use the provided blue stickers.  Since there is now an actual GFCI receptacle at that outlet, those stickers are no longer necessary and can be removed. Many people do not like them.

Now if you want to modify that, and have only the first couple of outlets be GFCI and the rest of the string plain outlets, then you can attach the plain outlet string to the LOAD terminals of that GFCI (only) and off you go.  They require the labeling, though you don't need to use the blue stickers - any marking will suffice as long as it is not handwritten. In fact, making custom labels is good because it will let you state the location of the reset.

Comment: Can you explain what is the end result of these steps? Will each outlet be individually GFCI protected?

Comment: @stannius yes, the answer would make each one be individually protected by its own GFCI

Comment: This is the correct solution. But do note that it can be partly implemented - for example adding a new GFCI outlet just one step down the chain (making the first one stand-alone), might be enough to solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming what you have is one outlet with a GFCI device that provides GFCI-protected power to other outlets in the room.

It's unlikely that you can move it.   The GFCI-protected outlets are all connected together but the one that is the GFCI device is also connected to the circuit feeding it all, to non-GFCI power.  That non-GFCI feed from the breaker needs to be available in the box where you put the device.   It's unlikely to be in any of the other boxes, but if it is, you could rearrange them.

There are some important details I won't get into here, but if you think it's possible you can elaborate in the question.

If you have unfinished space directly above or below the room it might be easy to feed power from the existing GFCI location to another one. Not as easy as just shuffling outlets around but not too hard either, just running a new cable vertically through walls from the unfinished space.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps. You could move your GFCI outlet/module to a newly-created convenient location upstream of your current GFCI outlet if you can figure out where exactly the wire powering the existing GFCI runs back to the panel, and install a new electrical outlet box on that run. It's probably best to have an electrician do such a job, but chances are it won't be too complicated for them.